# Amazon Lex fallback function to Amazon Alexa or Google Assistance

Tags: python, google-assistant-sdk, amazon-lex

I created Amazon Lex bot, I would like to know can I connect Amazon Alexa skills or Google assistance to the amazon lex bot,
so whenever it encounter the fallback function it should go through alexa or google assistance and respond to the general questions.

Example:
Q- what's the weather today?

Thankyou

Comment: Can you briefly explain the scenario, so that I can help you?

Comment: ok.. I build a chatbot using Amazon Lex and its working fine. when the user ask any question which is not available in the intents the bot will respond as "Sorry, can you please repeat that?" so insted of error message i want to provide answers from amazon alexa or google assistant 
So is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible with Alexa or either with google assistant, but you can achieve that by using `Google Custom Search` (but keep in mind if you are new to Google Custom Search it may take time to R&D) where you send the query **, for Example,** - "what's the weather today" then take that query and do an api call to `googleapi` and when you get the result give them back the top five results from the google. You can get more information [Here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview). I hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this, but you should be able to add logic to the fallback to use the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview) or [Amazon Voice Services](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-voice-service) to programmatically call one of the assistants with a query and receive a response.

But this would be extending the SDKs in a way that isn't entirely optimal, so you may run into some occasional odd behavior.