# Talk to Alexa API without any specific skill

Tags: api, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit

I need to create an intent-based chatbot with AWS Lex. It has some intents and responses, but if it doesn't identify any specific intent, it must get a response from Alexa (e.g., "What time is it now?", "What is the height of Lady Gaga?"), so that it looks more natural. Voice is not needed, just plain text.

There's a Alexa simulator available in Alexa developer console [(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIYVe.png), which is exactly what I need, bit I couldn't manage to reproduce it in a programatic way (API's or containers). I've tried to use a container with Alexa Skill Kit (ask), but it simulates only custom skills, not full Alexa behaviour. Everything I found on internet relates to creating Alexa Skills, but I don't want a Skill, I just want the regular responses from Alexa.

What could be a manner to talk to Alexa via API or Docker, so that given a phrase it returns an Alexa response? It doesn't need to be Alexa, provided that it returns responses for those simple questions, but so far Alexa seemed to be the best choice for answering them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

angelo,

It sounds like there are two parts to your question.

1. How to configure a catch-all type intent in Lex
2. How to call Alexa programatically

With regards to Lex, you can make use of the [built-in Fallback intent](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/managing-conversation-flow-with-a-fallback-intent-on-amazon-lex/) which will handle all inputs that Lex is not able to correctly assign to an intent, slot etc.

By adding a Lambda to the Fallback intent, you can then invoke the [Alexa API's](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/handle-requests.html)  with the user's input.

Comment: The problem is in part 2. From the [Skill Simulation API documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-simulation-api.html):
  
_This API is only available for custom skills._
  
It means the standard intents and responses from Alexa are not available. I just needed to have simple answers for questions like "When was soccer invented?"

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59573381/9771745) post, It's not possible to use an API to talk to Alexa just as one would do with an EchoDot, even for plain text. The simulation tool from developer console, which allows to talk to Alexa normally, is restricted to the web page.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).